# Fast $L^{1}$ Convergence implies almost uniform convergence

Tags: measure-theory

$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lVert f_{n}-f \rVert_{1} < \infty$ implies $f_{n}$ converges almost uniformly to $f$, how to show this?

EDIT: Egorov's theorem is available. I have been able to show pointwise a.e. convergence using Chebyshev and Borel-Cantelli, I am having trouble trying to pass to almost uniform convergence using the absolute summability condition...

Comment: Do you have Egorov's theorem available, or are you being asked to show this directly? It might help if you provided some more background context about where this question comes from, what you already know, and so forth.

Comment: Let $F:=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (f_n -f)$. The assumption implies that $F$ is defined almost everywhere and is integrable. If $\mu$ is your original measure, consider now the measure $dF=Fd\mu$ and apply Egorov's theorem to an appropriate function in this new (finite!) measure space.

Comment: [Have you considered accept the answers to your questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3286/8271)

Comment: @Mark Your hint seems preferable to the brute force proof, but I can't quite figure out what you mean.  You're integrating with respect to a new measure $\mu_F(A) = \int_X F \mathbb{I}_A d\mu$ right?  What is the 'appropriate function'?  I noticed that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise with respect to $\mu_F$, but applying Egorov doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put $g_n:=|f_n-f|$, and fix $\delta>0$. We have $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lVert g_n\rVert_{L^1}<\infty$ so we can find a strictly increasing sequence $N_k$ of integers such that $\sum_{n\geq N_k}\lVert g_n\rVert_1\leq \delta 4^{-k}$. Put $A_k:=\left\{x\in X:\sup_{n\geq N_k}g_n(x)>2^{1-k}\right\}$. Then $A_k\subset\bigcup_{n\geq N_k}\left\{x\in X: g_n(x)\geq 2^{-k}\right\}$ so 
$$2^{-k}\mu(A_k)\leq \sum_{n\geq N_k}2^{-k}\mu\left\{x\in X: g_n(x)\geq 2^{-k}\right\}\leq \sum_{n\geq N_k}\lVert g_n\rVert_1\leq \delta 4^{-k},$$
so $\mu(A_k)\leq \delta 2^{-k}$. Put $A:=\bigcup_{k\geq 1}A_k$. Then $\mu(A)\leq \sum_{k\geq 1}\mu(A_k)\leq \delta\sum_{k\geq 1}2^{-k}=\delta$, and if $x\notin A$ we have for all $k$: $\sup_{n\geq N_k}g_n(x)\leq 2^{1-k}$ so $\sup_{n\geq N_k}\sup_{x\notin A}g_n(x)\leq 2^{1-k}$. It proves that $g_n\to 0$ uniformly on $A^c$, since for a fixed $\varepsilon>0$, we take $k$ such that $2^{1-k}$, so for $n\geq N_k$ we have $\sup_{x\notin A}g_n(x)\leq\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|f_n - f\|_{L^1} < \infty$, where

\begin{align} \|f_n - f\|_{L^1} = \int_{X}|f_n(x) - f(x)| dx. \end{align}

Let $k \geq 1$. By the absolute summability assumption, for a sufficiently large positive integer $N_k$,

\begin{align} \sum_{n=N_k}^{\infty} \|f_n - f\|_{L^1} < 4^{-k}. \end{align}

Now, let

\begin{align} E_{n,k} = \{ x \in X : |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 2^{-k} \}. \end{align}

Then we have a simple bound

\begin{align} \sum_{n = N_k}^{\infty} m(E_{n,k})2^{-k} \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \|f_n - f\|_{L^1} < 4^{-k}. \end{align}

So,

\begin{align} m\left(\bigcup_{n = N_k}^{\infty} {E_{n,k}} \right) \leq \sum_{n = N_k}^{\infty} m(E_{n,k}) < 2^{-k}. \end{align}

Let $E = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n = N_k}^{\infty} {E_{n,k}}$. This is a set of measure zero. Moreover,

\begin{align*}
E^{C} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n = N_k}^{\infty} {E_{n,k}^{C}} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\{ x \in X : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq 2^{-k} \hspace{5pt} \forall n \geq N_k \}
\end{align*}

That is, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on the set $E^C$. Thus, $f_n$ converges almost uniformly to $f$.

Comment: I dont think this works. The set $E$ is dependent on $\delta$.

Comment: You're likely right. It's been a while since I've thought about this.

Comment: The argument is salveagable. You just need to do a bit more bookkeeping.

Comment: Fixed it! Hopefully I didn't introduce more serious errors. Always learning from my mistakes.

Comment: The last step is incorrect. You should instead take the union over $k$ in the definition of $E$. For the convergence to be uniform, the condition $$\begin{align}
\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right| \leq 2^{-k} \forall n \geq N_k
\end{align}$$ must hold for arbitrary $k$.

Then putting an epsilon would control the measure of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $g_n:=|f_n-f|$ and let $\delta >0$ be given. We need to show that there exists $A\subset X$ with $\mu (A)<\delta$, such that for any $k>0$ there exists $N>0$ so that for all $n>N$ and all $x\notin A$, $g_n(x)<\frac{1}{k}$.

Define $B_{n,k} := \left\{x\in X:g_n(x)\ge \frac{1}{k} \right\}$ and $A_{N,k}:=\bigcup_{n>N}B_{n,k}$. By Markov, we have:
$$\mu (A_{N,k})\le \sum_{n>N}\mu (B_{n,k})\le k\sum_{n>N} ||g_n||_1\mathrel{\mathop{\longrightarrow}_{\mathrm{N\to\infty}}} 0. $$

Thus for each $k$, let $N_k$ be an integer such that $\mu (A_{N_k,k})\le \frac{\delta}{2^k}$. Let $$A:=\bigcup_{k>0}A_{N_k,k}.$$

Then $\mu(A)\le \delta$. Moreover, for a given $k>0$, take $N=N_k$, so for any $n>N$ and $x\notin A$, $g_n(x)<\frac{1}{k}$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

I'll directly refer to the corresponding exercise in Tao's "Introduction to Measure Theory".

(Fast ${L^1}$ convergence) Suppose that ${f_n, f: X \rightarrow {\bf C}}$ are measurable functions such that ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n-f\|_{L^1(\mu)} < \infty}$.

Show that ${f_n}$ converges almost uniformly to ${f}$.

Proof: Fix an $\varepsilon > 0$. Since ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n-f\|_{L^1(\mu)} < \infty}$, we can make the "tail" of the series arbitrarily close to $0$. In particular, $\forall k \geq 1$, $\exists N_k$ such that $\sum_{n \geq N_k}\|f_n-f\|_{L^1(\mu)} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{k\cdot2^k}$. By Markov's inequality, we then have:
$\mu(\{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{k}, \text{for some}\ n \geq N_k\}) = \mu(\bigcup_{n \geq N_k}\{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x) \geq \frac{1}{k}\}) \leq \sum_{n \geq N_k}\mu(\{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{k}\}) \leq \sum_{n \geq N_k}k \cdot \|f_n-f\|_{L^1(\mu)} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2^k}$.

We then define $E_k := \{x \in X: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{k}, \text{for some}\ n \geq N_k\}$ and let $E = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$.

Note that $\mu(E) \leq \varepsilon$. Also, $\forall \delta > 0$, there exists some $k$ such that $1/k \leq \delta$, hence $E_k \subset E$ and we thus have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{k} \leq \delta$, $\forall n \geq N_k$, $\forall x \in X \setminus E$. i.e, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ outside of $E$.

Comment: I'm not sure this works. note that:
$$E^{\complement} = \cap E_k^{\complement} = \cap\{x\in X:|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{k}\ for \ some \ n \geq N_k\}$$

Comment: @KhaledAlekasir: Proof edited.